# Meaning of the word 'latest'

Tags: meaning

I don't understand meaning of the word "latest" in the next sentence:

> Ivanka Trump’s personal assistant latest to test positive for
>   coronavirus

Could you please clarify what does it mean?

Comment: Yes, there was a headline of the NY Post

Comment: It's [headlinese](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese). "Forms of the verb "to be" and articles (a, an, the) are usually omitted."

Comment: Thanks, @Rattler!

Comment: Am I understand right that the full sentence should look like "Ivanka Trump’s personal assistant *the* latest *who* to test positive for coronavirus"?

Comment: Ivanka Trump’s personal assistant _is/was  the_ latest (person in the WH) to test positive for coronavirus

Comment: Thanks again @Rattler!

Answer (score 1):

Here the word 'latest' is used in the context of other whitehouse officials testing positive for Coronavirus. Trump's valet and other persons have already tested positive.

Without stating the above facts, the headline is saying Ivanka Trump's personal assistant is the most recent of a few whitehouse persons to have tested positive.

The use of the word here is correct and the writer does so to make the headline short. He assumes that the reader already knows that other persons have tested positive before Ivanka's personal assistant.